# Display AppBar on certain condition

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-widget

1. Is it possible to Bring down or display the appbar only when the draggable sheet reaches the top of the page in flutter?
2. And having another doubt.

Is it possible to navigate from the home page to another page that has a transparent background and displays the home page as the background? Something like widgets placed on the stack...

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that you’ve tried so far?

Comment: For the first one I tried but I didn't get any solution, that is not proper.

Comment: You can include that much you’ve tried

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to the draggableScrollableSheet and get its offset. Then based on the offset you can hide or show the Appbar.. To get a transparent screen use PageRouteBuilder with opaque: false. Check this demo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: CustomPaintIssue()));

class CustomPaintIssue extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPaintIssue({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool showAppbar = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: showAppbar ? AppBar() : null,
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                          opaque: false,
                          pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => SecondPage()));
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DraggableScrollableSheet(
                maxChildSize: 1,
                builder: (context, scrollController) {
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController
                      ..addListener(() {
                        if (scrollController.hasClients &&
                            scrollController.offset > 50) {
                          setState(() {
                            showAppbar = true;
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            showAppbar = false;
                          });
                        }
                      }),
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 1500,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(
              5,
              (index) => Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```